# Is Rust's support for fork() cross-platform?

Tags: rust

I know Rust can handle windows and *nix filesystems. I saw there is support to fork processes - is this also cross-platform? Would I be able to write a *nix daemon and a Windows service with the same codebase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as `fork` on Windows (it uses `CreateProcess` instead).

More generally, Unix daemons and Windows services are very different (the latter has to comply with specific Windows interfaces), so you would need a significant abstraction layer if you want to share some code base. As far as I can tell, there is no library providing such an abstraction layer yet.

Comment: FWIW there is a rust crate for abstracting the windows service api https://github.com/mullvad/windows-service-rs

Comment: For sure, there are crates to help create services and such, but those are not cross-platform as requested by the OP.